# Scrambling variables and inserting them into file c++

Tags: c++, variables, random

I am creating a c++ quiz maker which offers a user the ability to insert different types of questions and answers and it inserts all that info into a neat file. The whole code is [here](https://github.com/JUNKJACKZACK/Quiz_Maker). My issue is that after gathering input to create a 'connect the word to definition' I do not know how I would scramble the variables of each word and definition to print out something like this:

1.) Connect the definitions to the word.

```
Astronaut                An expert of automobiles.
Mechanic                 An individual that has been to space.
Pilot                    An individual who is knows about electronics.
Electronic engineer      An individual who is skilled in flying planes.
```

```
void connectDefinitions() {
    fstream file;

    if (!file) {
        cout << "Error when opening file.";
    }

    file.open("quiz.txt", ios::app);

    if (file.is_open()) {
        counter = 0;

        file << current_numbered_question
             << ".) Connect the definitions to the word.";
        file << "\n\n";

        while (counter != 4) {
            cout << "What is the word you would like to add?\n";
            cin.ignore();
            file << "\n\n";
            getline(cin, user_word);

            cout << "What is the definition of the word you added?\n\n";
            cin.ignore();
            file << "\n\n";
            getline(cin, user_def);

            if (counter == 0) {
                connectword1 = user_word;
                connectdef1 = user_def;
            }
            if (counter == 1) {
                connectword2 = user_word;
                connectdef2 = user_def;
            }
            if (counter == 2) {
                connectword3 = user_word;
                connectdef3 = user_def;
            }
            if (counter == 3) {
                connectword4 = user_word;
                connectdef4 = user_def;
            }

            counter++;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Appending numbers to variable names is a very strong indication you need an array. Then you would be able to use `std::random_shuffle` to shuffle the definitions.

Comment: Instead of four separate variables you need arrays. One array for your words and one array for your definitions. I'm sure you must have covered arrays (or even vectors) on your course at this point.

Comment: I meant to mention that I think I have to include an array but what would that look like with my situation. Do you know off hand what it would like to append numbers to variables names?